# HTML - How to translate page content using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am doing the following in order to translate my HTML page:

```html
<p data-key="paragraph-1">Hello world</p>
<p data-key="paragraph-2">This is a translated text!</p>

<div ...>
  <a data-key="aboutPage" href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

```js
const translations = {
  "es": () => ({
    "title": "¡Hola mundo!",
    "subtitle": "¡Este texto ha sido traducido!",
    "routes": {
      "aboutPage": "Sobre",
    }
  }),
  ... 
}

const t = _.memoize(
  (
    scope,
    language = getNavigatorLanguage() ?? DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    fallbackLanguage = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    fallbackText = ""
  ) => {
    const formattedLocale = language.split(/[-_]/)[0]; // Short version: "en", "es", "it"...

    const translation = // fallback
      (translationGetters[formattedLocale] ?? translationGetters[fallbackLanguage])();

    return (
      _.get(translation, scope) ??
      _.get(translationGetters[DEFAULT_LANGUAGE](), scope, fallbackText)
    );
  },
  (...args) => JSON.stringify(args)
);


$(() => {
  $("*[data-key='paragraph-1']").text(t("title"));
  $("*[data-key='paragraph-2']").text(t("subtitle"));
  $("*[data-key='aboutPage']").text(t("routes.aboutPage"));
});
```

I come from React Native, where I could simply do:

```js
<Text>
  {t("routes.aboutPage")}
</Text>
```

But I am not sure if it is a good practice (maybe is wrong for SEO or just not good) to do something like this on HTML:

```html
<p>
  <script>
    t("title")
  </script>
</p>
```

Would I have to use selectors in order translate all my content? Any advices?

Comment: For SEO you need a server-side translation.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: Create Translation Function

Let create a new JavaScript file called "translate.js" and then write code to get translation text from JSON file in folder lng based on the selected language.

```js
 function Translate() { 
    //initialization
    this.init =  function(attribute, lng){
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.lng = lng; 
    }
    //translate 
    this.process = function(){
        _self = this;
        var xrhFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //load content data 
        xrhFile.open("GET", "lng/"+this.lng+".json", false);
        xrhFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(xrhFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(xrhFile.status === 200 || xrhFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var LngObject = JSON.parse(xrhFile.responseText);
                    var allDom = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
                    for(var i =0; i < allDom.length; i++){
                        var elem = allDom[i];
                        var key = elem.getAttribute(_self.attribute);
                        if(key != null) {
                            elem.innerHTML = LngObject[key]  ;
                        }
                    }
                
                }
            }
        }
        xrhFile.send();
    }
}
```

STEP 2: Switch Language Function

Create a new JavaScript file named "index.js" to begin the translation process

```
//This function will be called when user click changing language
function translate(lng, tagAttr){
    var translate = new Translate();
    translate.init(tagAttr, lng);
    translate.process();
    if(lng == 'en'){
      $("#enTranslator").css('color', '#f4623a');
      $("#khTranslator").css('color', '#212529');
    } 
    if(lng == 'kh'){
      $("#khTranslator").css('color', '#f4623a');
      $("#enTranslator").css('color', '#212529');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  //This is id of HTML element (English) with attribute lng-tag
  $("#enTranslator").click(function(){
    translate('en', 'lng-tag');
  });
  //This is id of HTML element (Khmer) with attribute lng-tag
  $("#khTranslator").click(function(){
    translate('kh', 'lng-tag');
  });
});
```

STEP 3: Define Your Translation Text in JSON

Let define translation text in JSON file as below

STEP 4: Embed Translation into Your Website

- Import both JavaScript file "index.js" and "translate.js" to HTML page

```js
<script src="js/translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

- Set selected language when first loading the page

```
<body id="page-top" onload="translate('kh','lng-tag')">
```

- Define HTML element with attribute "lng-tag" for the text you wanted to be translated and value of attribute is the key which define in JSON file

Here is the static website which implements the above method to translate language between Khmer (CAMBODIAN) and English https://praject.co/

Comment: Then, by dynamically parsing all the DOM, by attribute, your JSON file looks linear right? No nesting.